# Building a poker probabilities calculator - how can I collect data about objects which keep getting deleted and recreated?

Tags: javascript, aggregation, poker

I'm currently working on a poker probabilities calculator, which basically exists to predict a user's odds of winning a game of poker, based on his/her starting hand. It 'plays' millions of games, then aggregates how often each starting hand resulted in its owner having the highest ranking hand.

I have a lot of the game-playing code already worked out, which you can see below:

```
function playPoker(tableSize) {

//Create the players, the deck and the card table which stores the 5 cards the players have in common
var players = createPlayers(tableSize);
var deck = createDeck();
var cardTable = new CardTable();

//Deal each player two cards
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
        deal(deck, players[j]);
    }
}

//Put five cards down on the table
for (k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    deal(deck, cardTable);
}

//Check for various winning hands here for each player
for (m = 0; m < players.length; m++) {

    //Merge the player's two cards with the five cards on the table
    var subjectCards = (players[m].cards).concat(cardTable.cards);

    //Make an array of the values of each of the seven cards, which will be used to determine 4 of a kind, 3 of a kind and pairs
    var valuesInOrder = getValuesInOrder(subjectCards);

    //Create a dummy array, so that valuesInOrder remains unchanged
    var straightValues = valuesInOrder.slice();

    //Remove any duplicate card, meaning that the array contains only unique values (i.e. 2, 4, 5, 7, K ... NOT 2, 2, 2, 8, K, K, A)
    var straightValues = straightenUp(straightValues);

    //Calculate how many pairs are in the hand
    var numPairs = howManyPairs(valuesInOrder);

    //Check whether the player has a royal flush, the highest ranking hand - then check the other hands by ranking
    checkRoyalFlush(subjectCards, straightValues);

    checkStraightFlush(subjectCards, straightValues);

    checkFourOAK(valuesInOrder);

    checkFullHouse(valuesInOrder)

    checkFlush(subjectCards);

    checkStraight(straightValues);

    checkThreeOAK(valuesInOrder);

    checkTwoPairs(numPairs);

    checkPair(numPairs);

}

}`
```

Basically, each card is an object with a suit property (from 1 to 4) and a value property (from 2 to 14). I've got all the logic for calculating rankings working pretty effectively - but I don't know how to collate the data for each card object (i.e. how often K♥ K♠ led to the highest ranking hand, how many times out of 50 million?)

Obviously I could create if-statements which increment every time the right starting hand wins, but I'd need to make 52^2 of them. Does anyone have a more elegant solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: All you want to track is the number of wins for each hand? Have you considered a dictionary with the hand as the key?

Comment: i would just redact suit and store each deal as a string under an object key with a number value that increments everytime it's to be counted. that way, you don't need to hand-code anything and a simple Object.keys(counts) loop can do all your reporting at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a dictionary with 169 keys, all the unique starting hands. Their exact suits don't matter, only if they're suited, rainbow or a pair. With such a dictionary you can increment the corresponding value of the highest ranking hand.

Comment: So 169 key and value pairs? Will I need to write out each potential starting hand though?

Comment: You'd need a function that classifies a starting hand. Eg 8h9d -> 98o, AhKh -> AKs. If this works you can increment the value if the key already exists or add it. The length of the resulting dictionary could also be used as a check that you generate all 169 distinct pairs in the first place.. To generate percentages you probably want to keep track of number of times a hand lost, since they aren't uniform. There are only 4 possible AA hands and 12 possible AKo hands.

Comment: Thanks for a great comment. Good point with the lack of uniformity among  starting hands too. So with the classification function, that would just take both the values of the two cards, place them in order of magnitude (i.e. 2, 4; J, K; etc.), determine whether they're of the same suit or not, then save that information as a string (i.e. KAs or 89o, as you say)?

Comment: Thanks, how do I actually go from having a string representing a pair of cards (i.e. KAo) to recording the wins/losses for such a card?

Comment: @Zetland, you can use another dictionary with `{won: 0, lost: 0}` or add your own datastructure. If this answer helped you solve the problem, please consider accepting it.